How much time should I wait for a professor response before contacting another one in the same university?
I send an email for a professor that I'm interested to work with him. He asked for my cv. I sent my cv in the same day. He didn't reply. I sent a reminder next day then there was two days off. How much time should I wait before contacting another professor?  and he might not reply??

Unless there's a reason that you haven't shared in your question, you can send the same request to more than one prof at the same time.

You leave many details out. Responses should differ by the customs of the field and the country. For example, in Computer Science, most Ph.D. students are supported, which means that faculty will be very careful about selecting students. In pure Mathematics, few faculty will have more than one or two concurrent Ph.D. students. This also means that they will be very careful about selecting students. In these examples, evaluation and consideration will take usually more time than a week.
In general, you have not made yet a(n implied) contract with the professor you selected and are therefore free to contact others. You run of course the risk of getting two "bites", but it is reasonably common for students to end up with a different group after coming to a university, so that faculty should not hold this against you.
